# useEffect passed argument is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

So I'm new to react hooks and can't seem to understand how useEffect works...

I have a hook:

```
const [print, setPrint] = useState(false);
```

a useEffect:

```
  useEffect((x) => {
    console.log("2nd => ",x)
  }, [print]);
```

and then I have a button function:

```
const btnPrint = async () => {
      let x = 1;
      console.log("1st => ",x);
      setPrint(true);
  };
```

**after a button press, the output is:**

```
1st =>  1
2nd =>  undefined
```

Why is `x` coming out as `undefined` in the useEffect function?

Thank you

Comment: What do you expect it to be? The `useEffect` callback does not accept a parameter.

Comment: Thank you.... TIL

Answer (score 1):

The *useEffect* function will never receive any argument. It's just a function that will be called when any of the dependencies you specify change (in this case, the value of `print`).

It seems like this is not a *useEffect* hook use case. What are you trying to accomplish here exactly?

Comment: You answered my question actually, for some reason I thought I could pass an argument in there.

Answer (score -1):

first of all:
the `let` keyword declares the variable in block scope. 

This means that it can't be accessed outside the block of btnPrint function.


Secondly, useEffect is a lifecycle hook. This means that it runs when the component is either mounted or unmounted. If you pass an empty array, it only runs once. If you pass an array of references to other variables, functions, etc., it runs whenever the provided variables change.